# Web.API in AKS, License

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, azure-aks

I need to deploy a Web.API Rest Service in azure-AKS using Windows containers. Until now, I was deploying ASP.NET Web Services using IIS (with the corresponding license). In AKS, is Web.APi Service published in IIS (and I need also a license) or Windows container has already the ability to publish this service? I'm new in this area and it's confusing for me.

Comment: When deploying api to Azure-sdk, the first step is to containerize your application, you can choose windows or Linux.You can refer to this, the main steps are similar. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetesAfter that, refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli

Comment: Hi Bruce, The application will be containerized in windows. It's a .NET Application with c dependencies which cannot be migrated to .NET Core (not without a high cost). My doubt is related to windows-container itself, and if it requires/uses IIS to publish rest services or windows-container publish services itself.

Comment: Although Windows is used as a container, the service release still depends on iis, which is built into the windows container.